# Does this Theorem 2 from Dandapat et al. imply that $\gcd(\sigma(p^k),\sigma(a^2)) > 1$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors-multiples, perfect-numbers

Write the odd perfect number $m=p^k a^2$ as a product of primes
$$m = p^k {p_1}^{2a_1} \cdots {p_v}^{2a_v}.$$
(Note that it is known that $v \geq 9$ by work of Nielsen.)  Let $N(m)$ be the number of subscripts $i$ for which there is a subscript $j$ such that
$$\gcd\Bigg(\sigma({p_i}^{2a_i} {p_j}^{2a_j}), p_i p_j \Bigg) > 1.$$

In **Theorem 2** in Dandapat, Hunsucker, and Pomerance's [Some new results on odd perfect numbers (1975)](https://msp.org/pjm/1975/57-2/pjm-v57-n2-p07-p.pdf), it is proved that

> **THEOREM 2** If $m$ is an odd perfect number, then
> $$v + 1 - \bigg(\log(v+1)/\log(2)\bigg) \leq N(m) \leq v.$$

**Theorem 2** shows that $N(m)$ is not even close to $0$, but more nearly $v$.

Here is my:

> **INQUIRY:** Does **Theorem 2** imply that $\gcd(\sigma(p^k),\sigma(a^2)) > 1$?

It *should* be possible to prove this implication, but I am not seeing it.

Comment: If you are willing to use a different approach here is what you can do. If we assume the contrary then $\sigma(p^k)=2z^2$. You can finish for $k>1$ by using the overflow post here to conclude https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285507/a-modification-of-the-ljunggren-nagell-equation?rq=1